# Input field is not getting focused on click and disappear behind the keyboard

Tags: jquery, html, blackberry

I'm developing an application based on jQuery. The issue is that I have an input field where I tap on it, the keyboard of my phone popup. However, the field is still behind the keyboard and I need to scroll my screen to see the field.

In my HTML page I did the following:

```
<script>
      $('#div1').click(function() {
            $('#p2EmpContPer').focus();
        });
</script>

<div id= "div1" class="float-right mobile-input-container">
    <input id="p2EmpContPer" type="text" class="font14 format-decimal inline-block" value="" /> 
</div>
```

What I want is when I click on the input field, I need the keyboard to popup (which is already working) and the app will focus on the field (which I'm unable to accomplish).

Issue is appearing on **Blackberry** devices only.

The app is built using Cordova.

Comment: No offence but you still build keeping blackberry users in mind.Amazing!

Comment: I know, we are using Worklight to develop our app, and 40% of our users are suing Blackberry and the issue is appearing on their devices. :(

Comment: Have you tried `scrollTop()`?

Comment: I haven't tried that actually. I will give a try. I believe it will be like " $('#div1').scrollTop(), right?

Comment: Something better would be like this:  `$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#yourDiv").offset().top}, 2000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply tell your html to scrollTop to the offset of your input field like so:

```
$('#div1').click(function () {
  var offsetTop = $('#p2EmpContPer').offset().top;
  $('#p2EmpContPer').focus();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: offsetTop - 20
  });
});
```

Check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/626q8bu4/)

Btw.: I added several Test Div's to your code to make the effect more visible.